# How do I remove code duplication to make a generic function to handle all kind of entities in Rust?

Tags: rust

I have asteroids; players and lasers are entities. Instead of the following code, is it possible to make one function that takes generic as argument and produce the same output. I understand ECS is an ideal way of handling this. But am curious if this would be possible.

```
// check collision between asteroid and players
pub fn check_collission_between_asteroid_and_players(asteroids: &mut Vec<Asteroid>, players: &mut Vec<Player>) {
    for player in players.iter_mut() {
        for asteroid in asteroids.iter_mut() {
            if player.entity.position.distance(asteroid.entity.position) < asteroid.radius + player.radius {
                player.kill();
                asteroid.kill();
            }
        }
    }
}

// check collission between player and players
pub fn check_collission_between_player_and_players(players: &mut Vec<Player>) {
    for player in players.iter_mut() {
        for other_player in players.iter_mut() {
            if player.entity.position.distance(other_player.entity.position) < player.radius + other_player.radius && player != other_player {
                player.kill();
                other_player.kill();
            }
        }
    }
}

// check collission between lasers and players
pub fn check_collission_between_lasers_and_players(lasers: &mut Vec<Laser>, players: &mut Vec<Player>) {
    for player in players.iter_mut() {
        for laser in lasers.iter_mut() {
            if player.entity.position.distance(laser.entity.position) < player.radius + laser.radius {
                player.kill();
                laser.kill();
            }
        }
    }
}


// check collission between lasers and asteroids
pub fn check_collission_between_lasers_and_asteroids(lasers: &mut Vec<Laser>, asteroids: &mut Vec<Asteroid>) {
    for laser in lasers.iter_mut() {
        for asteroid in asteroids.iter_mut() {
            if laser.entity.position.distance(asteroid.entity.position) < laser.radius + asteroid.radius {
                laser.kill();
                asteroid.kill();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: make it generic, use a trait "Kill" implement kill for every type, you already did that, done. For better answer provide better mce

Comment: Yes, you'll want to write a trait for objects that can have collisions and be killed. You'll run into some minor issues with the player-player collision since that would have to take two mutable references to the same data. Also, `&mut Vec` should only be used if you intend to resize the vector. `&mut[...]` is more general in your use case.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement a Trait that can collide and kill, and use a generic function:

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
struct Position {
    x: f64,
    y: f64,
}

struct Player {
    position: Position,
}

struct Asteroid {
    position: Position,
}

trait Collidable {
    fn position(&self) -> Position;
    fn kill(&self);
}

impl Collidable for Player {
    fn position(&self) -> Position {
        return self.position;
    }
    fn kill(&self) {
        println!("Aaarghhh, Player dying at coordinate {:?}", self.position);
    }
}

impl Collidable for Asteroid {
    fn position(&self) -> Position {
        return self.position;
    }
    fn kill(&self) {
        println!("Aaarghhh, Asteroid dying at coordinate {:?}", self.position);
    }
}

fn check_collisions<T: Collidable, U: Collidable>(t_vec: &mut[T], u_vec: &mut[U], max_dist: f64) {
    for t in t_vec.iter_mut() { // Note you're now comparing the same objects twice in some cases
        for u in u_vec.iter_mut() {
            let t_pos = t.position();
            let u_pos = u.position();
            // Some calc to determine distance:
            let distance = ((t_pos.x - u_pos.x).abs().powf(2.) + (t_pos.y - u_pos.y).abs().powf(2.)).powf(0.5);
            if distance < max_dist {
                println!("Collision!");
                u.kill();
                t.kill();
            }
        }
    }
}

let mut players = vec![
    Player { position: Position {x: 1.0, y: 1.0}},
    Player { position: Position {x: 3.0, y: 3.0}}];

let mut asteroids = vec![
    Asteroid { position: Position {x: 2.0, y: 2.0}},
    Asteroid { position: Position {x: 10.0, y: 10.0}}];

check_collisions(&mut players, &mut asteroids, 5.);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Rob's answer, here is a version that uses **Trait Objects** so that you have *one* method that will check *all* collisions between objects. The code is mostly the same except for the `check_all` method and the way you have to construct the vector:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
struct Position {
    x: f64,
    y: f64,
}

struct Player {
    position: Position,
}

struct Asteroid {
    position: Position,
}

trait Collidable {
    fn position(&self) -> Position;
    fn kill(&self);
}

impl Collidable for Player {
    fn position(&self) -> Position {
        return self.position;
    }
    fn kill(&self) {
        println!("Aaarghhh, Player dying at coordinate {:?}", self.position);
    }
}

impl Collidable for Asteroid {
    fn position(&self) -> Position {
        return self.position;
    }
    fn kill(&self) {
        println!("Aaarghhh, Asteroid dying at coordinate {:?}", self.position);
    }
}

fn check_all(t_vec: &mut[Box<dyn Collidable>], max_dist: f64) {
    for i in 0..t_vec.len() {
        for j in i+1..t_vec.len() {
            let i_pos = t_vec[i].position();
            let j_pos = t_vec[j].position();
            let distance = ((i_pos.x - j_pos.x).abs().powf(2.) + (i_pos.y - j_pos.y).abs().powf(2.)).powf(0.5);
            if distance < max_dist {
                println!("Collision!");
                t_vec[i].kill();
                t_vec[j].kill();
            }
        }
    }    
}

fn main() {
let mut objects: Vec<Box<dyn Collidable>> = vec![
    Box::new(Player { position: Position {x: 1.0, y: 1.0}}),
    Box::new(Player { position: Position {x: 3.0, y: 3.0}}),
    Box::new(Asteroid { position: Position {x: 2.0, y: 2.0}}),
    Box::new(Asteroid { position: Position {x: 10.0, y: 10.0}})];

check_all(&mut objects, 5.);
}
```

I'm using explicit indices `i` and `j` instead of grabbing the objects to avoid the problem that you can't have two mutable references to vector elements at the same time.

Btw, in the *current* version of the code we don't actually need the vector elements to be mutable, but *probably* in real code where the `kill` method does something to the object, we'd need to make it `fn kill(&mut self)` instead.

Comment: Using objects just unnecessarily slows down your code. Iterating over a range and indexing something with yielded values is a pretty bad practice.

Using `return` here is a bad pattern too...

Comment: Feel free to actually post an answer that addresses these concerns. I'll grant you the `return`.

Comment: For example, trait objects indeed trade off convenience for a (tiny) performance hit. 

And accessing two mutable vector elements at the same time would be a problem; e.g. itertools' `combinations` won't work for `&mut vec`, especially if you don't want to clone.